# Combine numerous lists of different length in python in an alternating order

Tags: python, list

If i have a few lists

I am able to combine list 1 with list 2 however, I have not managed to succeed to combine the other lists.

```
def alternator():
    iets = []
    for i in range(len(list2)): 
        something += [list1[i]]
        something +=[list2[i]]
    result = something
    result_weaver(result)

def result(x):
    list31 = list3
    if len(list3) < len(x) :
        while len(list31) != len(x):
            list31 += '-'
```

I decided to add '-' in order to make sure the lengths of both lists were equal, so the for loop could go to work.

Does anyone have better ideas on how to program this ?

Comment: You created `iets` then the rest of the function uses `something`; I happen to know that `iets` is Dutch for `something`, but Python won't translate that for you. :-P

Comment: Hahah that is correct, I edited the whole thing now :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) here:

```
try:
    from itertools import zip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

def alternate(list1, list2):
    return [v for v in sum(zip_longest(list1, list2), ()) if v is not None]
```

The `zip_longest()` call adds `None` placeholders (similar to your own attempt to add `-` characters), which we need to remove again from the `sum()` output after zipping.

Demo:

```
>>> alternate(list1, list2)
['1', '5', '2', '6', '3', '7', '8']
>>> alternate(alternate(list1, list2), list3)
['1', '9', '5', '2', '6', '3', '7', '8']
```